# Intgration by parts formula for $\varphi \in C_C^{1}(\mathbb R^n)$

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral, fubini-tonelli-theorems

Let $\varphi \in C_C^{1}(\mathbb R^n)$ show that
$$\int_{\mathbb R^n} \nabla \varphi(x) dx=0$$
i´m a litle confused with the notation $\nabla \varphi(x)$ because $\varphi$ is a scalar field, the hint of these exercise is use Fubini's theorem and fundamental theorem of calculus but i not sure how can use these.
Any hint or help i will be very grateful

Comment: It is quite obvious from FTC if you know the definition of integral of a vector valued function. Try it first for one-dimensional case.

Comment: @geetha290krm sorry i dont see the obvius, you can recomend me some book about of these?

Comment: Did you try the one-dimensional case?

Comment: Yep $\int_{\mathbb R} f'(x)dx= \int_{a}^{b} f'(x)dx=f(b)-f(a)=0$ the first equality is like the support of $f$ is compact and the third is because $f$ vanishes in the frontier of the support, is correct?

Comment: Yes. It is the same idea for $\mathbb R^{n}$. See what happens when you integrate w.r.t. the first variable $x_1$.

Comment: oh i see, maybe im confused with respect of the notation, in these case $\nabla \varphi$ is the gradient of $\varphi$?